$\partial (x+y)$/$\partial (x+y)$=$\partial x$/$\partial (x+y)$?
Obviously, $\partial(x+y)$/$\partial (x+y)$=1
but value of $\partial x$/$\partial(x+y)$ is also 1.
How come for $\partial y$/$\partial (x+y)$ is 0 instead 1 in this case? How can I explain this? I think both terms should be 1 but it will give value of $\partial z$/$\partial z$ 2 where $x+y = z$?

What does $\frac{\partial}{\partial(x+y)}$ mean?

We have $x = (x+y) - y $ so do we partially differentiate $x$ res $x+y$ and result is 1?Same holds for $y$ since we are doing two operations per each?

But if you add both and apply additive rule the result is contradictive. I don't see what is going wrong here...

The notation $\frac{\partial}{\partial x+y}$ doesn't make much sense. $x+y$ is not an independent variable. The one way it could be made to work is as a directional derivative (see here).
In this case we have $\frac{\partial}{\partial x+y}f(x) = \nabla_{(1,1)} f(x) = (\nabla f) \cdot (1,1) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.
In this case we actually have $\frac{\partial x+y}{\partial x+y} = 2$. Which is weird.
